# JSF: Get managed bean instance (war file) from another library (jar file)

Tags: jsf, javabeans, instance, managed

I have the following structure:

**Jar File**

- `SecureTagHandler`: Component where I need get the user credentials to check.
- `UserSession`: Abstract class

**War File (Jar dependency)**

- `UserSessionBean`: Extend to UserSession, is annotated with `@Named` and `@SessionScoped`, store user name, credentials, etc.

I need a solution to get an `UserSessionBean` reference/instance in the Jar File, I need use the user credentials stored in `UserSessionBean` to secure components using my `SecureTagHandler`. I don't want to use annotations in the JAR file. I can't inject the `UserSessionBean` because the class name can be changed.

**UserSession**

```
public abstract class UserSession implements Serializable {

    private static UserSession userSession;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        UserSession.userSession = this;
    }

    public static UserSession getUserSession() {
        return userSession;
    }
}
```

Comment: As injection is not currently possible in TagHandler i would go with ELResolver.

Comment: You are correct, I can use ELResolver, but is not my idea because the Managed Bean's name can be changed. I need an alternative solution that permit me to reuse this code more easily.

Comment: Parametrize the bean name as parameter in web.xml

Comment: @adrianm Good approach. I added the UserSession code, do you understand what I'm trying to do? actually this works, but I don't know if is correct or exists a best suggestion. I don't like to use the PostConstruct annotation in this case. When I call the method within constructor (maybe a bad practice) I got sometimes empty variables.